# CSS: border around image moves it

Tags: css, css-transitions

So i have my image on my webpage. In my css code, i have a transition for a `:hover` (glow appears), which works fine, and i want to add a stroke on `:active`. Here's my code :

```
#bb
{
    top: 55%;
    left: 6%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#bb:hover
{  
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
#bb:active
{
    opacity: 1;
    border: 10px solid rgba(87,87,87,0.8);
}
```

my problems are the following : how do i get the stroke to appear *around* the image without moving it, and how do i get it to stay "active" without having to hold the click on the image?

Comment: make a fiddle. What do you mean by without moving it.

Comment: `border` takes up space -- try `outline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS **box-sizing:border-box;**. Write like this:

```
#bb:active
{
    opacity: 1;
    border: 10px solid rgba(87,87,87,0.8);
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/4g6d9/

Answer (score 2):

A border occupies space, so adding a border normally displaces an element. If you use the `outline` property instead of `border`, no displacement takes place—but the outline will appear on top of anything that would otherwise appear in the same place, i.e. may cover other content.

The meaning of `:active` has various interpretations in different browsers. To make specific things happen (as cross-browser as possible) on keyboard or mouse events, you need to use JavaScript.